# React Hooks Update Dictionary State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state that should be a dictionary like so:

```
[personInfo, setPersonInfo] = useState({"firstName": "", "lastName": ""});
```

I want to update this state like so:

```
setPersonInfo(prevPersonInfo => prevPersonInfo["firstName"] = "name")
```

But this is not working.

Please do not recommend that I store two separate states for firstName and lastName. For my particular use case, it is necessary that I use a dictionary.

Comment: That is not immutable way to set state, so instead, return the object using ...rest and your changed key: value. `setPersonInfo(ppi => ({...ppi, firstName: 'name'}))`

Comment: what you do is mutating the object (which is a big NO NO in react land), you have to create a new brand object like so `setPersonInfo(prev => {...prev, firstName: 'SOME_NAME'})`

Comment: I created a simple custom hook with an useReducer for that, check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-dictionary

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that it isn't working because you are altering the same object, instead of returning a new one.  I'd recommend rewriting it in a way that spreads into a new object

```js
setPersonInfo(prevPersonInfo => ({...prevPersonInfo, firstName: "name"}))
```

Incidentally, depending on how complex your object is getting you might want to consider [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

Comment: For me it works only if I put brackets around the key value. Such as: ...., [firstName]:"name" ... do you know why that's the case?

Comment: @J.Smith - I'd need to see your code in context to be certain, but if you're constructing an object like this: `{ [firstName]: "name" }`, then the only way I'd see that working is if `firstName` is a variable name in scope, and the object will have a property of that variable name.  So if you have `const firstName = "Jay"` and then `const myObj = { [firstName]: "name" }` I'm going to expect the value of `myObj` to be `{ "Jay": "name" }`.